# How to debugg javascript called from an qt executable in windows?

Tags: javascript, qt, debugging

i am working currently on a desktop application (programmed in qt) for which i only have the executable, (no source).
This executable calls a very big javascript file for which i have the source. (The javascript file does some template magic to generate excel sheets whith LibXL on windows)

Now i have to refactor and improve the javascript file.

Is there any way to debugg the javascript?

Comment: What JS engine is being used?  Can you run the JS yourself in an engine like node?

Comment: Qt has been supporting a JavaScript engine compatible with ECMAScript-262 since Qt 4.3. This engine is called “QtScript” and was originally an independent implementation. Since Qt 4.5, QtScript has been based on JavaScriptCore from WebKit.

Comment: You only have two choices here.  1) Find out from QT how to debug JS in their environment.  2) Figure out a way to run the JS in another environment (like Node) where you can debug.